# how does array[1-'a'] work in c programming?

Tags: c

I'm working on a program to find the anagram to two strings in c. But I end up in a statement

```
array[1-'a']++;
```

and I don't quite know the working of that statement.
Anyone out there help me..!

Answer (score 5):

ASCII value of `'a'` is `97`. `1 - 97` is `-96`. `array[-96]` is equivalent to `*(array - 96)`. If `array - 96` is a valid address then `array[1-'a']++;` will give the value at address `array - 96` incremented by 1, otherwise dereferencing it will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

`'a'` is a *character constant* and it is an integer which is the character code of `a` (97 if ASCII code is used).

`array[1-'a']` is equivalent to `*((array)+(1-'a'))`, which is `1-'a'` element after (`'a'-1` elements before) the element pointed at by `array`. `++` is *incrementing*, which is equivalent to adding 1. `array[1-'a']++` is *postfix increment*, so this expression will be evaluated to the value of `array[1-'a']` *before* incrementing.

An example of possible usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    int data[SCHAR_MAX] = {0};
    int* array = &data['a'];
    printf("%d\n", data[1]); /* 0 will be printed */
    array[1-'a']++;
    printf("%d\n", data[1]); /* 1 will be printed */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array[1-'a']++;
```

- `a` is ASCII 97.
- `1 - 97` is `-96`
- `array[-96]`, if a valid address, is `96` elements before the base address of `array`
- `++` increments its operand, or `array[-96]`.

This code, however, is highly dubious in its correctness.